# Subject is in wrong order when call next in operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive

I have a subject, then I apply `map(x => x/*not the real function*/)` operator on it. But the map operator has some side effects, it will emit new value in some cases.

[Here's the example](https://runkit.com/zeekozhu/rxjs-emit-in-operators):

```js
const sub = new Subject();
const emits = [];
const mapped = [];
const emit$ = sub.asObservable().subscribe(x => emits.push(x));
const data$ = sub.asObservable().pipe(
    map(x => {
        return x;
    }),
    tap(x => mapped.push(x)),
    tap(x => {
        if (x % 2 === 0) {
            sub.next(2333);
        }
        if (x === 2333) {
            sub.next(1111);
        }
    })
);
const datas = [];
data$.subscribe(x => {
    datas.push(x);
});
sub.next(1);
sub.next(2);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('emits: ',emits);
    console.log('mapped: ', mapped);
    console.log('datas: ', datas);
}, 10);
```

when the input sequence is [1, 2], the subject's subscriber will receive [1, 2, 2333, 1111],but the mapped observable's subscriber will receive [1, 1111, 2333, 2].

UPDATE:

I move the side effects into a `tap` operator, and store the mapped emissions into a array, then the result become:

```
emits: [1, 2, 2333, 1111]
mapped: [1, 2, 2333, 1111]
datas: [1, 1111, 2333, 2]
```

Here is the questions:

1. Is this the correct behaivor?
2. Should I emit new value in operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior here is non-intuitive because `Subject`s have a different semantics to ordinary Observables.

Per [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject), `Subject`s have a semantics similar to `EventEmitter`s: they keep track of their subscribers internally, and *synchronously call all of the listeners* when a new event is emitted.

In your example, the `tap` operator is synchronously feeding new events into the `data$` Observable. So each time it calls `next()`, it immediately triggers the `pipe` chain for the new value **before the `tap()` handler returns.**

To better observe this behavior, [this example](https://runkit.com/bgran/subject-stack-trace) logs when the `tap` operator enters and exits, and also prints the stack.

When you run the example, you'll see that the `pipe` chain runs for `1111` and `2333` before the final `tap` handler for `2` returns. You'll also see that the call stack of the `1111` and `2333` events still contains the `pipe`/`tap` calls for the `2` event.

Why does the `emit$` observable have events in a different order? `emit$` is subscribed directly to the `Subject`, so its listener synchronously runs as soon as `next` is called. From the perspective for `emit$`, the order of `next` calls is `[1, 2, 2333, 1111]`.

`datas$`, on the other hand, has to wait until the final `tap()` operator returns before the subscriber is called. So when the `2` event passes through the final `tap`, `datas$` doesn't see it until processing of `1111` and `2333` finishes.

### Should you emit new values in operators?

Generally, no. Why? Because it's very difficult to understand what's going on, even in a relatively straightforward example like this (where everything is called synchronously).

Imagine if an ordinary non-Subject Observable was somehow included in this example. The order of operations would be extremely difficult to trace, and the callstack becomes less useful for debugging because it gets cleared for each tick of the event loop.

In general, only emit new values in operators if you're **sure you need this exact semantics**. If there's a way to represent your logic without doing so (by e.g. using ordinary non-Subject Observables), or even better, without using `Subject`s at all, then it will be much easier to reason about the code.

Comment: What if I use `setTimeout(() => sub.next(value), 0)` to emit values in operators, I have updated my example code. Can the problem be fixed in this way?

Comment: There's not really a "problem" here: this is just how `Subject` works.
If you schedule the `next` calls with `setTimeout`, there is now a race condition: we don't know if the `setTimeout` handlers scheduled within `tap` will run before the `setTimeout` that logs the arrays.

Using `setTimeout` _will_ result in `emits`, `mapped`, and `data` having the same order.