# RXJS emits wrong values in subscription again

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have to make changes based on an observable.
These changes are dependent on the previously transmitted data. However, the second subscription always emits the new value first and then the old value.

Is there a way around this?
Or is there a better way to fix the problem.

```ts
const mysubject = new BehaviorSubject({ name: 'FOO' });

mysubject.pipe(map((res) => `Hello, ${res.name}!`)).subscribe(console.log);

mysubject
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilKeyChanged('name'),
    tap((res) => {
      if (res.name === 'FOO') {
        mysubject.next({ name: 'BAR' });
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);



LOG:
Hello, FOO!
Hello, BAR!
{name: "BAR"}  <--- emits first
{name: "FOO"}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nm2xbd?file=index.ts

Comment: As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50199169/3558960)?

Comment: add `delay(0)` at the end of your pipe

Comment: Okay yes I get the point, thanks. delay(0) at the start of the pipe will fix this problem